# Rails: How to maintain an in-memory, in-process search index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I believe we can get a massive performance boost in our user matching and search feature if we keep a simple in memory data structure of some nested hashes and arrays. This is not sophisticated enough to use a dedicated in memory search like ElasticSearch and it's not mostly about free text search either. The question is how to keep it updated?

So I'm thinking of reserving one thread at load time to refresh and replace this index stored in a class variable every 5 minutes or so (it only takes a second or two to do this). The trouble is that this feels janky. Reserving a whole thread just to mostly sit there sleeping! Might it be better to just spawn a short lived thread after each request to check if it's time to update? But I don't want this always fighting for CPU with the request at exactly the wrong moment. Short of introducing an evented library like event machine **is there a more standard railsy way to do this?**

I understand that such shared state when not managed by some intermediary like redis is generally discouraged but I'm pretty comfortable about mutation risk as I'll be freezing this data structure. Also, this index has a few tens of thousands of hash keys and text items so I imagine deserializing from redis for every request is going to defeat much of the benefit.

Comment: So you are running a single ruby process?

Comment: No, many processes, a good few clusters but it's affordable to have a copy of the data structure per process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since found [sucker punch](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch), a  popular gem which is [strongly recommended](https://github.com/mperham/girl_friday) by the creator of sidekiq.

I wouldn't say it's the perfect answer as it's not designed for long running threads and is maybe overkill when I can just launch my own short lived threads on a controller callback.

Other answerers make the good point that with multiple processes I'll need a synchronisation method. Redis fits the bill and I will use it. However, if we follow the premise of the question that the structure is too big to deserialize from redis on each request then we need some additional in-process concurrency to maintain a shared deserialized cache object.

I understand why other answerers are uncomfortable with such strategies as ruby really isn't geared for in-process parallelism so it isn't a big part of our culture (until the mythical ruby 3.0 we can only do concurrency in-process). This can't mean it's never the right answer.

Suckerpunch addresses the requirement of background processing in a railsy way - a lot like sidekiq - but *in-process* so with direct shared object access.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit of a contradiction; you're simultaneously asking for a Railsy way to solve your problem, while explicitly discounting all the common solutions and insisting that your invented plan is the best fit.

It sounds like you're going to end up going to a lot of effort to hand-roll a "less sophisticated" solution. I strongly recommend against that. However:

Whether you choose timed or evented expiry will largely depend on whether you have a single cache, or multiple independent ones. If it's an in-process cache, and you have more than one process, you have no practical way to trigger expiry on demand, and will have to take the timer approach. (I don't see how event machine would be in any way relevant here.)

Redis is indeed a far more appropriate tool for this job. The point of using Redis is that you don't need to deserialize everything: you do the lookup in Redis, and then only deserialize the part that matches.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have said railsy but "a sane way that rails devs might use". Some context: I had previously been pushing this search microservice in a more nicely railsy AR object oriented direction. But now we're expecting serious, sudden growth and performance is now the primary concern. Ruby will more than suffice in performance given the right decisions. The data structure is a hash with arrays of ids pointing back to the hash. It typically requires > 1000 key accesses per request. To make redis work I'd need a much more complex and heavily denormalised data structure.

Comment: If the question is purely about the reasonableness of having a thread dedicated to maintaining the freshness of this cache (and we're hand-waving the thread-safety concerns that come along with that), then yes, that's a perfectly reasonable thing to do. Active Record has a thread whose only job is to occasionally look for DB connections that have been misplaced. Threads (particularly mostly-idle ones) really aren't _that_ expensive.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. As for the problem of it being multi-process I recognise the weakness is that there will need to be one copy of this data structure per process. It occurs to me that for consistent results they will need to be closely synchronised. The most efficient way of doing this would be to indeed bring in redis to store the result with a worker and have one thread per process deserialize it every 5 minutes. Yeah it's getting a little more complex than desired. Still less so than alternatives I can see but hmmm..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple processes AND multiple hardware: having stale, out of sync data is innevitable. 
Inventing your own caching solution (for lookup, expiry, synchronisation, refresh, preload and guarding it against eating all your memory, ...) will be more complex and error prone than to just use something that already exists (Redis comes to mind, there are others).

I suggest you look at [Rails caching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) with the Redis store. 
While this will include Network/Deserialization I'd say this is the most Rails way and, in my experience, is fast enough.
If you have tried this and it is still to slow, then you can try another solution. Or roll your own. But first measure, don't just assume.

Comment: Ok, but I use redis caching a lot and explained why it would not fit this bill and you haven't addressed that explanation. As for questions of stale data, fortunately the part which will get most benefit from this caching is a slowly changing dimension and represents our curated business knowledge about how user attached tags are correlated with each other. The fast changing dimension of which tags users possess is inexpensive to live query. On the question of inconsistency, that's a theoretical but real concern and you can refer to the conversation beneath matthewd's answer.

Comment: You "imagine" it is slow. That is not really an explanation.
If want to roll your own solution before trying something proven (which would be much easier to use/implement) go ahead, the additional thread will not hurt you.

Comment: Indeed, I've decided that the syncronisation concern is enough that I will use redis, will confirm that such a deserialization is too slow before adding the further layer of cached deserialized objects.

Comment: Please understand that I wouldn't have come looking for a battle tested alternative to the solutions I know and love if I didn't have a compelling performance need. This index lookup is just one part of a multi-stage searching process which needs to become reliably at least 6x faster but preferably more so we have headroom for platform growth and can continue to make the search algorithm more sophisticated. Avoiding a gigantic redis call and deserialization really matters in this context.